# Symfony: fetch with put request on route results in RuntimeException

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig, httpresponse

I'm trying to call a service method through a button click with the following code:

Twig HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="Ready Up" onclick="ready('{{ path('ready', {'playerName' : name}) }}')">
```

Javascript:

```
function ready(path) {
    fetch(path, {method : 'put'})
        .then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
}
```

Symfony Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/player/ready", name="ready")
 * @return Response
 */
public function toggleReady($playerName) {
    $this->gameCacheService->readyUp($playerName);

    return new Response('test');
}
```

Clicking the button results in the following exception:

```
 Uncaught PHP Exception RuntimeException: "Controller "App\Controller\PlayerController::toggleReady()" requires that you provide a value for the "$playerName" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one."
```

However, the generated URL looks to me like it actually does provide a value for '$playerName':

```
/api/player/ready?playerName=Testname
```

What causes this behavior?

Final HTML rendered in the browser:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <input type="button" value="Ready Up" onclick="ready('/api/player/ready?playerName=Testname')">
    <script>
        function ready(path) {
            fetch(path, {method : 'put'})
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                });
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How is that twig HTML rendered? Please provide the final HTML as it shows in the browser's source view. Also, are you sure you need to use PUT as method? Because that URL parameter is a GET parameter, afaik. PUT params are in the body, just like POST ones.

Comment: have you try to change the html to this onclick="ready('{ path: 'ready/name'}')"

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón Twig uses `{{ var }}` to insert values into HTML.

Comment: as i see the uri formed need to be : "/api/player/ready/Testname" have you configured httdocs?

Comment: @ChrisG I added the final HTML. I think it should be a PUT method, because the service method I call updates a cache entry

Comment: It doesn't really matter what the service *does*, it matters what it *expects*. GET is used for short, non-confidential data like search filters, and POST is used to transmit form data and files and the like. Other methods aren't really used anymore because they aren't needed. So unless your service specs specifically state you're supposed to use PUT, don't use it.

Comment: You can specify in route the dinamyc parameter: 

@Route("/api/player/ready/{dynamicParameter}", name="ready")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include the route param in the annotation :

```
/**
 * @Route("/api/player/ready/{playerName}", name="ready")
 * @return Response
 */
public function toggleReady($playerName) {
    $this->gameCacheService->readyUp($playerName);

    return new Response('test');
}
```